# Excel sumproduct across multiple columns on multiple sheets with multiple criteria

Tags: excel-formula, sumifs, sumproduct

I have 12 worksheets named Jan 2022 through Dec 2022. On each worksheet column B contains workgroups, columns E:J contain estimate numbers, and row 2 contains the work week.

On the summary worksheet I need to show the estimate for each work group for each work week. The summary worksheet is a large table, with column A containing the work groups and row 1 containing the work weeks. Cells B2:BB25 contain the sums of the estimates for the corresponding work group and work week.

I have the names of the 12 worksheets listed in a named range called SheetList.

I'll discuss the formula I have in B2.

Current Solution:
`=SUMIFS('Jan 2022'!E:E,'Jan 2022'!$B:$B,$A2)`

*this gives me the correct number, but I have to manually align each formula with each work week on it's respective sheets, sometimes having to add 2 sumifs together when a work week overlaps the change of month.*

I'm trying to develop a solution that doesn't require manual assignment of columns for each work week throughout the year. It's an error-likely manual process.

Here is what I've tried:

1. `=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'"&SheetList[Sheet Names]&"'!"&"$E:$E"),INDIRECT("'"&SheetList[Sheet Names]&"'!"&"$B:$B"),$A2))`
   *this sums for a single work group across all months, but i can't figure out how to add in another criteria where `INDIRECT("'"&SheetList[Sheet Names]&"'!"&"$e$2:$j$2")=B$1` so that it isolates the particular work week. Also, this would require 6 `SUMPRODUCT` formulas in each cell.*
2. `=SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT("'"&SheetList[Sheet Names]&"'!"&"$E$5:$J$1000"))*(INDIRECT("'"&SheetList[Sheet Names]&"'!"&"E$2:$J$2")=B$1)*(INDIRECT("'"&SheetList[Sheet Names]&"'!"&"$B$5:$B$1000")=$A2))`
   *this returns a `#VALUE` error. i think it's because i can't use `INDIRECT` in a `SUMPRODUCT` without a `SUMIFS`*
3. `=SUMPRODUCT(N(INDIRECT("'"&SheetList[Sheet Names]&"'!"&"$E$5:$J$1000"))*(N(INDIRECT("'"&SheetList[Sheet Names]&"'!"&"$E$2:$J$2"))=B$1)*(N(INDIRECT("'"&SheetList[Sheet Names]&"'!"&"$B$5:$B$1000"))=$A2))`
   *this returns "0"*

here's a link to the example file [2022 Monthly Estimates](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zOHV0Mih20se283DMHD7-oXO8enh5tTD/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105924493725115064677&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: a small sample of data for people to work with would be helpful.  Say 4-6 rows, and just a couple of work week columns to get an ideal of format and layout.  Avoid screenshot when possible to reduce the number or times people remake your spreadsheet to play with.

Comment: Sure thing! I've uploaded a trimmed down version of the file here [2022 Monthly Estimates](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zOHV0Mih20se283DMHD7-oXO8enh5tTD/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105924493725115064677&rtpof=true&sd=true) and edited my original post to include this link.